# Docker: Installing dotnet core on a windowsservercore image gives no output/unrecognised

Tags: .net, windows, docker

I need dotnet core when running the docker image to build a project I will be mounting on the image. When trying to call dotnet at runtime, no output is received, and the command does not terminate. When trying to run it during build, I now get the 'dotnet is not recognised as a command' error, but before it worked a few times. I am using the dotnet install script [from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-install-script). Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:11-windowsservercore AS runtime

WORKDIR /app

COPY reqs .

RUN powershell .\dotnet-install.ps1

RUN dotnet build project\TA2\TA2

ENV project_name TA2

ENV roslyn_sdk rsdk

EXPOSE 9000

CMD .\build.bat
```